# Add an individual layer from ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer to the map

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer containing many layers. I'd need to add only individual layers to the map, like layers 2,5 and 10.

The following code would add all the layers to the map:

```
url = "http://...MapServer";
mapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(url, {
     className: layer,
     opacity: opacity
});
map.addLayer(mapServiceLayer);
```

How can I add only i.e. layer 5 to the map? (.../MapServer/5)

There is a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37828/load-one-layer-from-arcgis-server-mapserver/39019#comment134715_39019) but answers seem not to be helpful for the front end solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this sample:

http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=map_explicitlayerlist

To set which layers are visible before the layer loads that it uses `ImageParameters`:

```
//Use the ImageParameters to set the visibleLayerIds layers in the map service during ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer construction.
      var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
      imageParameters.layerIds = [1,2];
      imageParameters.layerOption = ImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_SHOW;
      //can also be: LAYER_OPTION_EXCLUDE, LAYER_OPTION_HIDE, LAYER_OPTION_INCLUDE

      layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer",
        {"imageParameters": imageParameters});
      map.addLayer(layer);
```

Once the layer is added to the map you can use `setVisibleLayers()` and pass in an array of layer indexes (i.e. [5]) to turn layers off/on.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Also, I'm wondering if excluded layers would appear in the Table of Contents widget: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9b6280a6bfb0430f8d1ebc969276b109

Comment: Unfortunately, my TOC widget (link above) does not honor the imageParameters property and displays all the layers within ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer regardless of the imageParameters settings

Answer (score 1):

This should accomplish what what you want to do.

```
Layer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("yoururl/MapServer/5",);

map.addLayer(Layer);
```

Comment: Thanks. That would create a FeatureLayer.. I would like to stick with dynamically generated tiles.